# Formating Date from epoch is not set to 01/01/1970 00:00

Tags: java, date

I would need to get a way to interpret epoch time in a Date but I am having a strange behavior surely due to TimeZone...

Here is the small piece of code I'm having:

```
Calendar origin = Calendar.getInstance();
origin.clear();
origin.setTimeInMillis(0);
Date date_origin = new Date(origin.getTimeInMillis());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
System.out.println("Date origin "+sdf.format(date_origin));
```

and the output is "Date origin 01/01/1970 12:00" whereas I'm expecting 01/01/1970 00:00

Even if I'm trying to use Calendar instead of Date

```
Calendar origin_retrieved = Calendar.getInstance();
origin_retrieved.setTimeInMillis(origin.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println("Date origin from calendar "+sdf.format(origin_retrieved.getTime()));
```

I'm still having 12:00....
Don't know what I'm doing wrong....

Comment: Please note that `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` are legacy classes and have been superseeded by the `java.time` API for multiple reasons since Java 8 onwards.

Comment: Did you [read the Javadoc of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), particularly around what "h" means?

Comment: you're right....better to use "H"....works better now...thks